# Rails Ajax approach without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The different Rails 3/Ajax solutions I have come across show examples that retrieve data from a database.

I would like to make an Ajax call and have the server return data that does not come from a database.  The data actually comes from REST aware pages on the web.

Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: Do you want the client to make the (JSON) requests or do you want your rails server to do it?

Comment: Either would work, but I am more interested in what the best approach is from a 'rails' perspective.  I am new to rails, but an experienced software developer.

Comment: Both are suitable for different purposes. It's not particularly "railsque" to do one rather than the other. It depends on what you want do make.

Comment: Would you know of a "Good Practices" document for rails development?

Comment: How about the Rails guides? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ You'll have explain what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: First, thank you for responding to my questions.  I've used the guides and have found them quite helpful.  One of the problems with rails is there is a lot there and picking the right approach is not easy for someone like me who works alone.

Comment: Do you think the HTTParty approach is reasonable?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. You might as well ask me whether to write a loop or read a file. If you use HTTParty you are making server-side calls. I am not a fan of doing that when the source is "REST aware pages on the web". Unless you are absolutely certain that they'll always be available and respond fast, you will be building a potentially slow application, because Rails will have to wait for your external pages to respond before responding to the user.

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

```
# Use the class methods to get down to business quickly
response = HTTParty.get('http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json')
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

With [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem.

You will return results as usual with Rails, for example, you could call in your controller:

```
render json: response.body
```

If you want it AJAX you can call this controller I mention with:

```
$.get('my_rails_route');
```

Check your requirements, you could simply do:

```
$.get('http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json');
```

Without passing by Rails server.